Can a request be made with Faraday through an insecure HTTPS proxy?
I have a proxy server that has a self-signed certificate only, and I would like to configure Faraday to make requests through that proxy server over HTTPS.
A request can be made with cURL to test that the proxy is working as expected, using the following command:
curl --proxy-insecure "https://<PROXY-IP>:<PROXY-PORT>" "https://httpbin.org/ip"

and it returns a response with a warning:
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
{
  "origin": "<MY-IP-ADDRESS>"
}

I'd like to replicate this in ruby using Faraday, but I was not able to do so.
When I try to do it within ruby, I receive an error:
conn = Faraday.new(
  url: 'https://httpbin.org',
  ssl: { verify: false },
  proxy: { uri: 'https://<PROXY-IP>:<PROXY-PORT>' }
) do |x|
  x.request :url_encoded
  x.adapter :net_http
end

I receive the following error:
<internal:io>:63:in `read_nonblock': Connection reset by peer (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:218:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:199:in `readuntil'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:209:in `readline'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http/response.rb:42:in `read_status_line'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http/response.rb:31:in `read_new'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:1020:in `connect'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:976:in `do_start'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:965:in `start'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-net_http-3.0.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:112:in `request_with_wrapped_block'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-net_http-3.0.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:102:in `perform_request'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-net_http-3.0.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:66:in `block in call'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-2.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter.rb:45:in `connection'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-net_http-3.0.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:65:in `call'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-2.9.0/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:25:in `call'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-2.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:152:in `build_response'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-2.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:444:in `run_request'
    ... 5 levels...
<internal:io>:63:in `read_nonblock': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:218:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:199:in `readuntil'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:209:in `readline'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http/response.rb:42:in `read_status_line'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http/response.rb:31:in `read_new'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:1020:in `connect'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:976:in `do_start'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/net/http.rb:965:in `start'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-net_http-3.0.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:112:in `request_with_wrapped_block'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-net_http-3.0.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:102:in `perform_request'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-net_http-3.0.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:66:in `block in call'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-2.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter.rb:45:in `connection'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-net_http-3.0.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:65:in `call'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-2.9.0/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:25:in `call'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-2.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:152:in `build_response'
    from /Users/developer/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/faraday-2.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:444:in `run_request'

Is there a possibility to make the request as with cURL, using --insecure-proxy somehow?
p.s. used Faraday version:
irb(main):001> Faraday::VERSION
=> "2.9.0"

